# SQL Server : Derive Multiple Rows from a text string contained in a database

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a database that contains logging information. When a user uploads multiple files they show up as a text string in a record. I need to update another table with the names of the files that were uploaded.

In the below example, `File1.txt` and `File2.txt` are the file names:

```
PK   Description
----------------------------------
1    Path: [Path]:\folder\sub Upload Method: Html5 Browser: IE 10.0 IP: 1.1.1.1 Files: Name: file1.txt Size: 313 KB Status: Completed Name: file2.txt Size: 444 KB Status: Completed Total Size: 758 KB Elapsed Time: 2 seconds Transfer Rate: 286 KB/second
```

I need to obtain and insert the file name in a new table ignoring the superfluous information so that it would appear like so:

```
PK   Filename
-----------------------------------
1    file1.txt
2    file2.txt
```

Because different paths may be uploaded to, there is not a set number of characters that will be present before the first file. And although my example shows 2 files there could be more so I need to continue parsing file names from the text be there 1 or 10 or 50 of them. The file names are also not uniform but all of them are preceded by name.

Comment: So, you need to extract whatever there is between "Name: " and the next space, right?

Comment: Yes that would definitely get me going in correct direction

Comment: Google and learn about the PATINDEX() and SUBSTRING() functions in sql server.

Comment: You can use a recursive CTE to pull out the multiple file names from the field.

Answer (score 1):

## My recommended broad approach

This is a pretty typical use-case for a [user-defined table-valued function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms186755.aspx).

You essentially want to create a function that takes each value of your log `Description` as the main input parameter - probably also taking additional parameters to govern what the start and end of each interesting substring should be. (In your case, interesting substrings start after `Name:` and end just before `Size:`.)

The function extracts each interesting value and adds it to an accumulator table variable, which is then returned as the result of the function.

You can use such a function neatly over presumably-many rows of logging information, using `cross apply` or `outer apply` operators (explained around half-way down [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177634.aspx)), something like so:

```
select      L.Description
            ,R.Filename
from        dbo.uploadlogs                                        as L
cross apply dbo.my_tv_function(L.Description,'%Name: %','% Size:%')   as R;
```

This assumes the `my_tv_function` returns a column called `Filename` containing the split out filenames. (That's up to how you write the function.)

You could hard-code the patterns you want to search for into the function, but then it'd be less useful/transferrable to different styles of logging information.

For every Description, this will produce n rows in the result set corresponding to n files uploaded in that Description log.

Having got that it should be easy to add a new unique key column using `row_number()`.

## How to create such a user-defined function?

In a general sense, you're going to want to leverage two standard SQL functions:

- [Patindex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188395.aspx): finds out where a particular pattern in a bigger string first starts.
- [Substring](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx): slices a, well, a substring from a bigger string.

Combining these functions (or `patindex`'s closely related `charindex`) is a very common way to get hold of a consistent bit of a string, when you don't know where exactly it'll start (or how long it'll go on for).

### But this only gets me the *first* occurrence of the text I want!

This is where to bring in a [while loop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178642.aspx).  Looping in SQL is both often-maligned, and often-misused. However, it's a useful language construct and situations like this, within functions, are exactly where looping is both appropriate and effective.  To ensure the loop ends, you need to make the long string (the log `Description`) shorter on each time around, by cutting off the bit you've already found a filename in, and leaving everything beyond it.

There are other possible approaches without a `while` loop: in a general sense, this problem of "doing the same thing multiple times along a big string" can be solved recursively or iteratively, and a `while` loop is the iterative approach. In SQL, I prefer this approach.

## Putting it all together

I'm not sure if you wanted a complete code solution or just guidance. If you want to figure the actual code out yourself, stop reading about now... :)

Here's a SQL function definition that will do what I described above:

```
create function dbo.fn_SplitSearch (
    @searchString nvarchar(max)
    ,@startPattern nvarchar(255)
    ,@endPattern nvarchar(255)
  )
returns @fileList table (Filename nvarchar(255) not null)

begin 

  /***
      This table-valued function will return all instances of text
      starting with @startPattern, and going up to the last character before
      @endPattern starts. This might include leading/trailing spaces depending
      on what you define as the patterns.
  ***/

  declare @foundValue     nvarchar(255)  =''
  declare @startLoc       int            =0
  declare @endLoc         int            =0

  while patindex(@startPattern,@searchString)<>0
  begin

    set @startLoc         = patindex(@startPattern,@searchString)
    set @endLoc           = patindex(@endPattern,@searchString)
    set @foundValue       = substring(@searchString,@startLoc,@endLoc-@startLoc)

    insert into @fileList values (@foundValue)

    -- Next time round, only look in the remainder of the search string beyond the end of the first endPattern
    set @searchString     = substring(@searchString,@endLoc+len(@endPattern),len(@searchString))

  end

  return
end;
```

This will actually output results like this:

```
Filename
---------
Name: file1.txt
Name: file2.txt
```

including the `startPattern` text in the output. For me this is a little more generic and it should be easy to trim off the `Name:` bit outside the function if you want. You could alternatively modify the function to only return the `file1.txt` part.

Answer (score 0):

I would add some regex clr assembly to my database and then use regex match to extract file names.